# Remove all lines matching "(True)" or "(False)" from a variable in Bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell

I have a bash array of tests that I want to pass to MyShell, and then pass the same commands to bash, and verify the output. The current script worked well for earlier iterations of the project and helped me find many bugs and errors.

HOWEVER, my program intentionally (It's schoolwork, but the bash script isn't)
prints (True) or (False) on a new line. Other than that, the output is identical.

Could you help me with the (probably one line each of) syntax to delete all lines matching "(True)" or "(False)" from the variable outputMyShell?

EDIT: Here are 3 examples.

Input: (echo 1 && echo 2) || (echo 3 && echo 4)
MyShell Output: "1
2"
Bash Output: "1
2"
Test passed

Input: test -e src/
MyShell Output: "(True)"
Bash Output: ""
Test failed

Input: test -f src/
MyShell Output: "(False)"
Bash Output: ""
Test failed

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#INPUTS[@]}; i++))
do
    echo -e  "\nInput: ${INPUTS[$i]}"
    outputMyShell=$(./Myshell ${INPUTS[$i]})

    eval $(rm -rf bashCreatedDirectory)
    outputBash=$(eval ${INPUTS[$i]})

    #echo -e "MyShell Output: \"${outputMyShell}\""
    #echo -e "Bash Output: \"${outputBash}\""
    if [ "${outputMyShell}" = "${outputBash}" ]
    then 
        tput setaf 6;
        echo -e "Test passed"
    else
        tput setaf 1;
        echo -e "Test failed"
    fi  
    tput sgr0;
done
```

Comment: Could you boil down your problem a bit? The script doesn't seem very relevant to the question and the relevant content of `outputMyShell` is missing. If I understand correctly, you have two variables and want to compare them but ignore (lines containing?) `True` or `False`. It would help if you gave explicit examples of when two strings should be considered equal and different.

Comment: What's with the various `eval` lines? You seem to have complicated matters by an order of magnitude.

Comment: Which `sed` command exactlyedid you try, and how did it fail? Why do you need to output to be in a variable anyway?

Comment: @Socowi Exactly, One variable stores the output of the shell my partner and I are writing, while another stores the output of regular Bash, given the same input.  They should be identical but for (True) and (False), so I dont actually care whether I edit the string, or compare them while somehow ignoring the (True) and (False) lines.

Comment: You don't need `eval` or command substitution to remove the directory; `rm -rf bashCreatedDirectory` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your examples it seems like all you have to do is to remove lines that are either `(True)` or `(False)`. You can use `sed` to do so:

```
if [ "$(sed '/(True)\|(False)/d' <<< "$a")" = "$b" ]; then
    echo equal
else
    echo different
fi
```

This will print

- `equal` for `a="1 2"` and `b="1 2"`
- `equal` for `a="(True)"` and `b=""`
- `equal` for `a="(False)"` and `b=""`
- `equal` for `a=$'(True)\n1'` and `b=$'1'`
- `different` for `a=1` and `b=2`
- `different` for `a=$'(True)\n1'` and `b=2`

Comment: Very much appreciated! Bash is such a confusing language especially for beginners. Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm able to correctly guess what you are trying to accomplish, try this.

```
# We don't need to know the index; just loop over items
for input in "${INPUTS[@]}"; do
    # Prefer printf over echo -e
    printf "\nInput: %s\n" "$input"
    # Run comparison command
    if 
        # Don't use a useless variable
        ./Myshell $input |
        # Remove (True) or (False)
        grep -Exv '\((True|False)\)' |
        # compare
        cmp - <(eval $input)
    then
        tput setaf 6
        echo "Test passed"
    else
        tput setaf 1
        echo "Test failed"
    fi  
    tput sgr0
    # No eval necessary here
    rm -rf bashCreatedDirectory
done
```

Comment: Wow this is really neat and tidy, I really appreciate the time you spent to clean this up. It's working perfectly and looking good too now.

Comment: I edited to remove spurious semicolons and unnecessary `echo -e` invocations. I would perhaps still move the color codes to separate functions so they are easier to disable.